# How to use the SQLITE3 LIKE statement

Tags: iphone, sqlite, statements

I have problems running a dynamic LIKE statement in my project: 
this query works like a charm and returns all items with a 't' in their name:

```
const char *sql = "select * from bbc_ipad_v1_node where name LIKE '%%t%%'";
```

When I try to do this dynamically I do not get errors, but just an empty result. It seems that the value is null. I try to bind a string value 's' which outputs a correct value

```
NSLog(@"bbc_ : search menu items from db based on: %@",s);
const char *sql = "select * from bbc_ipad_v1_node where name LIKE '%%?%%'";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [s UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

How should I bind this value instead of using:

```
const char *sql = "select * from bbc_ipad_v1_node where name LIKE '%%?%%'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found a great explanation at http://www.innerexception.com/2008/10/using-like-statement-in-sqlite-3-from.html

I changed following lines:

```
const char *sql = "select * from bbc_ipad_v1_node where name LIKE ?001";
```

and

```
NSString *searchInput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", s];
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [searchInput UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just say

```
const char *sql = "select * from bbc_ipad_v1_node where name LIKE '%t%'";
```

(Note the single-`%`s)